# Tomcat cannot find development build of Java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, centos

My project has a Java servlet that extends `HttpServlet`.  In ops this servlet responds properly to AJAX calls to the server, which runs Tomcat 6.  The calls's URLs are of the form `host:port/App/Servlet(query-string)`.

I am adding a new AJAX call to the servlet.  I copy the servlet WAR file to the Tomcat `webapps` directory and bounce the tomcat service.  Then I run my project (from a tcsh script).  Calls to the servlet now return HTTP 404.

I see nothing in the Catalina log file indicating that the servlet even started, but no error messages as to why it wasn't found.  (I suspect there's some other log setting that I need to tweak and some other log file I need to review.)

I cross checked with another development server that runs the original servlet, and it has no problems.

What's off with the routing to the servlet, and how do I fix it?

ETA1:
The servlet has a list of calls: `Call1`, `Call2`, etc.  I added `Call3` to the list and reused the pattern for `Call1` as much as I could find.  Now both `Call1` and `Call3` return 404 errors.

ETA2:
I dropped the servlet WAR file from the other development server -- where the existing AJAX calls work properly -- onto this development server.  The calls continued to work properly.  Although I did notice a quirk that the build system runs JDK 1.7.0_51 and the app runs JDK 1.7.0_71.  I also copied the AJAX request's URL and went right to that location.  With the existing servlet, I got an AJAX response that was pretty much correct.  With my dev version, I got an empty page.

ETA3:
I'll clarify my scenario, based on feedback from the comments.

My project has a Java web app.  It runs properly in and of itself.

The app sends AJAX calls to a Java servlet.  This servlet works properly in operations.  Also, when I copy the release version to my development Tomcat 6 server, the release version works properly.

I added a feature to the servlet and deployed the WAR file to the development Tomcat server.  Now Tomcat complains it can't find the servlet (HTTP 404), even for identical calls and unmodified features that used to work properly.

As the release version works properly on the development web server, I conclude that Tomcat itself works properly.  I also conclude that there is no issue with the URL or the port.  As far as I can tell, Tomcat either can't start the servlet or the servlet fails before reaching its constructor.  I have not found the log file or logging setting that would show the failure.

Comment: So, the compiled servlet class is simply missing in /WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: @BalusC: Nope, all the `.class` files are present and accounted for: `Servlet$1.class, Servlet$2.class, Servlet$CALLS.class`, and `Servlet.class`.  The list matches between the release WAR file and my dev build.

Comment: OK, probably the URL is indeed just wrong. That HTTP 404 error page, is it the one from the client or server?

Comment: I observe the 404 error in the Network tab of the Firefox debugging tools.  When I go directly to the URL, the response page is empty.  FWIW, the servlet does not have its own error pages.  I can drop one in and see what happens.

Comment: Tomcat has a default 404 error page. [With marine blue headings and all](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+default+404+error+page&tbm=isch). If you didn't get this (so the 404 is from client), then this means that the domain and/or port is wrong. If you did get this (so the 404 is from server), then this means that domain and port is correct, but context path and/or servlet path is wrong.

Comment: And that default error page does not display.  I added to my question the fact that with the unmodified servlet, going direct to the URL returns an AJAX response, while doing the same test with the dev servlet returns blank.  Exact same URL destination and servlet command.

Comment: So the domain and/or port part of the URL is wrong. Or Tomcat hasn't started up. With the information provided so far, only you can check this. The problem is at least not in the WAR or the Servlet for now. So you have a smaller area to investigate the problem. Basically .. your problem now boils down to *"My Tomcat isn't reachable on `http://host:port`"*.

Comment: @BalusC: I have expanded my scenario description to address your last comment.  Tomcat itself is reachable, the web page and app are reachable, but the dev servlet is not.

Comment: Well, then we're back to the step where exactly the 404 is coming from. Client or server?

Comment: I believe it's coming from the server.  But how do I determine this for certain?

Comment: If you're using a webbrowser, it's usually done by just looking at the error page being visually presented when you hit `http://host:port`. Is it the client's or server's default one? And if you open up the "Network" tab in webbrowser's developer toolset, then you can also check this by presence or absence of response headers and body. If these are absent, then the server is clearly not behind the expected host and/or port.